# Obtain the rowname of the minimum number of a vector in Mata (Stata)

Tags: matrix, stata, min

I have a vector with dimension (50,1) in Mata. I would like to know how I can obtain the rowname of the minimum number of this vector.

Answer (score 0):

What did you try? A minimal standard here is that you show us what you tried and explain why it does not work.

Here's one way. Note that rows don't have names in Mata; your random numbers may differ; and in general two or more rows could have the same minimum.

```
mata
: y = rnormal(50, 1, 0, 1)
: select((1::50), (y :== min(y)))
11
: min(y)
-2.427600583
: y[11]
-2.427600583
```